# SQL select specific values in a joined table as columns

Tags: sql

I don't think I'm explaining it right in the title, but I have something similar to this SQL Fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/26812/2

Basic overview of the data: We're a manufacturing plant and our process is multi-step so for each order there are actually two created in our ERP system, the "SubOrder" to produce the base product and the "FinalOrder" to decorate and package it. For scheduling purposes I'm trying to link to the ERP software and pull specifications and component information for each new order, I found all the data I need and am able to join it all together, but the issue I'm running in to is bringing all of the info from the specs and BOM tables into a single row.

I'm trying to figure out how best to format it like:

```
OrderNmbr | PartName | SC1Spec | Cmp1 |....
```

Where SC1 is SPECS.SPECNAME WHERE SPECCODE= 'SC1' and Cmp1 is BOM.BCOMPONENTNAME WHERE BCOMPONENTNAME LIKE '%t E'

Comment: The second part of your question is nebulous. What is the expected output that you want, based on your fiddle?

Comment: @AlexandreSantos The specCode column contains an identifier for ea part specification, I'm looking to create a column in the results for some of those identifiers, i/e row 1 in the fiddle contains specCode "C1" with "SpecName "Part A" so the result column "C1Spec" would contain "Part A"